# Whether $x^3$ is a permutation on $\mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am taking a cryptography course requiring some number theory knowledge. The lecture notes say that $x^3$ is a permutation on $\mathbb Z_p$.

The original statement is:

> **Proposition**: $x^3$ is a permutation on $\mathbb Z_p$. Its inverse function is $x^u$,
> where $u$ is the multiplicative inverse of $3$ modulo $p-1.

Here, $p$ is a large prime with $\gcd(3, p-1)=1$.

Is there a typo in the above statement? Since $x^3$ may not be an element in $\mathbb Z_p$ for $x\in\mathbb Z_p$. I guess the correct statement should be $x^3 \mod p$ is a permutation on $\mathbb Z_p$. Could anyone tell me why it is true? I think we need to show that for every $x\in\mathbb Z_p$, $x^3 \mod p$ has a unique mapping in $\mathbb Z_p$. Thank you.

Comment: I think we need to show for $x,y\in\mathbb Z_p$ and $x\neq y$, $x^3\mod p\neq y^3\mod p$. But I get stuck here.

Comment: "Since $x^3$ may not be an element in $\mathbb Z_p$ for $x\in\mathbb Z_p$." $\Bbb Z_p$ is not the set $\{0,1,\ldots p-1\}\subseteq \Bbb Z$. It is the set $\{[0], [1], \ldots, [p-1]\}$, with each $[n]\subseteq \Bbb Z$ being equivalence classes, not numbers (except we usually do skip the brackets for convenience). We certainly do have $x^3\in \Bbb Z_p$ without any issues.

Comment: [Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: will $x^3 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$?  Arthur has already commented on that, so I will address the second part only.

You want to show that if $p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ (this is the outcome of the condition $\gcd(3,p-1)=1$), then
$$x^3 \equiv y^3 \pmod{p} \implies x \equiv y \pmod{p}.$$
Observe that
\begin{align*}
x^3 & \equiv y^3 \pmod{p}\\
(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) & \equiv 0 \pmod{p}.
\end{align*}
Using the prime property ($p|ab \implies p|a \text{ or } p |b$), we get that either $x \equiv y \pmod{p}$ OR $(x^2+xy+y^2)  \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

We will show that the latter **cannot be true** when $p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ (assuming that $x,y \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$).

Suppose $p$ divides $x^2+xy+y^2$ for some  $x,y \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then
\begin{align*}
x^2+xy+y^2 & \equiv 0 \pmod{p}\\
4(x^2+xy+y^2) & \equiv 0 \pmod{p}\\
(2x+y)^2+3y^2 & \equiv 0 \pmod{p}
\end{align*}
Since $\gcd(y,p)=1$, so $y$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Thus, we can write the last congruence as:
$$a^2 \equiv -3 \pmod{p}, \quad \text{ where } a=(2xy^{-1}+1).$$
If you know about quadratic reciprocity, then use that to show that $-3$ is a QR modulo $p$ implies $p \equiv \color{red}{1} \pmod{3}$. But the $p$ given to us is $2 \bmod 3$, hence the condition $(x^2+xy+y^2)  \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ won't hold.

Thus $f(x)=x^3$ will be a permutation on $\mathbb{Z}_p$, when $p \equiv2 \pmod{3}$.

**Note 1:** Just for the sake of completion: consider $p=7 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. Then $1^3 \equiv 2^3 \pmod{7}$, so $x^3$ will NOT be a one-one function on $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

---

**Note 2:** Another argument which is a bit group-theoretic in nature can also be made to establish the result. We assume that $x,y \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ such that $x^3 \equiv y^3 \pmod{p}$. Then $\gcd(y,p)=1$ implies that
$$(xy^{-1})^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}.$$
If $x \not\equiv y \pmod{p}$ in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, then this shows there exists and element of order $3$. This would mean that $3|\varphi(p)=p-1$. But that violates the gcd condition.

Answer (score 1):

This can be answered pretty briefly with some elementary group theory (which may or may not be of help to you).

The multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_p\setminus 0$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$. Let $n$ be a generator of this group. If $3\nmid p-1$, then $n^3$ is also a generator, and this generator only hits elements that are third powers. That means all the elements are third powers of some other element, so raising to the third power is a surjection. Since we have a finite group here, it is also an injection, and it's therefore a bijection / permutation.